# Map ESC to keyboard-escape-quit

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys, escape

I like Emacs but I hate the default shortcuts. I'm trying to make them more like Sublime Text, Atom, ...
Most shortcuts I can change without a problem, but `ESC` seems to be more difficult. I don't wont to press `ESC` 3 times or `C-g` to exit something. 
Can I remove `ESC` as a prefix key?

I tried this, but that doesn't work:
`(global-set-key (kbd "ESC") 'keyboard-escape-quit)`
It seems to break other shortcuts.

I use Emacs on Ubuntu 16, but I connect from Windows with putty. (I got all the function keys working under putty)

Comment: Rebinding `ESC` is generally not a good idea, IMO. It is hard-coded in some cases, among other things. If your main complaint is having to hit `C-g` or `ESC ESC ESC` to cancel an action, just what would you like to do instead to cancel an action?

Comment: I would like to use ESC (1x) to cancel an action.

Comment: Here is a link to something that may interest the original poster -- people of the new generation have a hard time adjusting to the `ESC` key doing more than one thing, and I struggled with it for at least a year.  Stefan wrote up a conditional usage of the `ESC` key that got me by the first year of using Emacs until I started to appreciate it as a modifier key.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026083/how-to-use-escape-conditionally-as-a-modifier-key  Now, I have even taken the `ESC` key a step further by separating it from the `Meta` key (which is beyond the scope of this thread).